# Can't get the display member function to print the modified values. Have included code snippets

Tags: c++

```
class Encrypt
{
public:

static const size_t arraySize = 8;

// constructor to get the integer 
explicit Encrypt(int);

int checkAndSetInt(int) const;  // tests and adjusts integers
void displayOriginalData() const; // displays first four elements of array 
void storeData(int) const; // takes and stores last four digits of integers   and encrypts and store them
      void displayEncryptedData() const; // displays last four elements of arrays    digits

private:
    std::array< int, arraySize > digits = {}; 
};
```

[Store data function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46uLQ.png) [Display data function and constructor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioKED.png)

I'm new to c++ programming so any help would be really appreciated. So I've written two member functions for a class. The purpose of one of them is to store the integer data in a class data member array and the other ones is to display that data from that array.

Now the problem i'm facing is that after storing the data in an array and call that display function to print that data, the initialized values(which are 0s) gets printed while when I put the task of printing data in the same function that stores that data the modified values print correctly.

Can anyone tell why is that and how can I get display function to print the values.

Comment: Don't put code in ***images***; copy them into your question.

Comment: It would help considerably to have a sample of the code in question pasted as *plain text*. An image needs to be typed out over again, plus it's located at an external link that might expire without warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have declared `digits` to be a local variable within `storeData`. If there is a class member within the `Encrypt` class, the class member is being hidden by the local variable...

To elaborate, when the compiler sees a line such as:

```
digits[4] = temp2;
```

It's going to go looking for the declaration of `digits` - it will begin by looking in the local scope (in this case the function scope), and if it doesn't find it the compiler will expand its search out to the class, to the local file, the global namespace, etc. The exact logic it uses is well outside the scope of this question, but the important thing is that in your case, the first thing it finds is the line:

```
array<int, Encrypt::arraySize> digits;
```

within `Encrypt::storeData()`. So it stops. It never finds `digits` within the `Encrypt` class because it already found it in the function! So it modifies the version of `digits` within the function, and when the function returns, it happily destroys the function-local `digits` (along with all the alterations you've made) and goes on its merry way. `Encrypt::digits` never gets modified at all.

The solution is to remove the line `array<int, Encrypt::arraySize> digits;` from `Encrypt::storeData()`, and also to remove `const` from the function declaration, because if your function's purpose is to modify the class' data, it shouldn't be `const` in the first place.

Comment: Hi, so i've included my Encrypt class. Could you tell how can I fix it. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but could you style it such that the entire class is within the code block? It's nigh-unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Sure. I can do that :)

Comment: Well, close enough I suppose - you should really look at the help documentation on how to post code blocks. Anyway, I've updated the response to elaborate on what's going on...